# SSIS "Execution Report" error - 'Report invalid' -- intermittently comes up in SSMS - cause?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, report, etl, execution

seems like every time in a blue moon, there will be a week straight where I can't view Execution reports for SSIS packages running in SQL Server. I will get a cryptic error message about:

> The definition of the report is invalid

Here is a picture:

[image]

Assuming I can't figure out this cryptic error (maybe you can) -- what steps do I need to go through to ensure I can view Execution Reports for SSIS jobs? I have separate custom logging --- it's more for a "live look" of some running jobs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having this very issue. The solution that worked for me was closing all SSMS windows and restarting Management Studios. I spent a few days failing to find a solution to the issue online before restarting the application so I hope this will save someone else that time.

Comment: simply restarting was enough to solve the problem?  with not change to the application?

Comment: Thanks. I actually discovered this myself, but forgot this question was open. Yes, restarting the SSMS client solves whatever this cryptic error is attempting to say.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install SQL Server Shared Management objects to fix this issue.

SQL Server 2017:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

Older versions of SQL Server, you can find it as a part of the Feature pack:

- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)